# Cannot sign-out from Facebook using flutter with firebase

Tags: facebook, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter app where I am authenticating  with Facebook and firebase on iOS. However, I cannot get the login in page again although I am calling the logout function

I always get the facebook confirmation screen which has some text that inform  me that I have already logged in.

How do  I logout so that the next time I am ask to enter my email/pass

here is a snippet of my code

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithFacebook();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithFacebook() async {
    FirebaseUser user;
    var result = await _facebookLogin
        .logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);
    if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
      FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
      AuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
      user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
    return user;
  }


Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase saves the `FirebaseUser` object in cache so the user won't need to re-signin every time he leaves the app. So the signOut function should look like this:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
    _user = null;
  }
```

And the `FirebaseUser user;` should be moved out of the signInWithFacebook function (I renamed it to `_user`).

Comment: How do I get the login screen again.